# How to configure SQL Server 2008 to take automatic backup daily?

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup

Hey anyone know how to take automatic backup of a SQL Server database once a day (or it may be daily or periodic bases)?

If you know any configuration of SQL Server then please tell me.

Or you may have solution by using a C# / .NET Windows application, then please also tell me.

Comment: You can simply use SQLBackupAndFTP (https://sqlbackupandftp.com) to make automatically backups.

Comment: What do you want? A tool or to do it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's quite easy!

Use SQL Server Agent. From SSMS go to "SQL Server Agent". Expand "Jobs", right click and select "New job". Go to "Steps" and add "New" step. Write your T-SQL code for SQL backup.

Go to "Schedules" and create new job "Schedule".

Finally, check if your agent has been started.

EDIT: You can also use "Maintenance Plan Wizard" from "Management" group, it's even easier because Wizard should generate (almost) all of the code for you and set up the Agent job.

Answer (score 0):

Created a scheduled job, and look at the following to create the backup http://www.sqlexamples.info/SQL/tsql_backup_database.htm.

It makes use of `BACKUP DATABASE @db_name TO DISK = @fileName;`

Comment: Remember, the user running your program will need permission to write on @fileName.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third-party products though. Check this opensource backup windows service [MFSQLBackupService](https://github.com/MohammadFneish7/MFSQLBackupService), it did a great job for me.